# SSH disconnected after start docker on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssh

I installed docker on aws according to thes docs

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

The ssh disconnected when i start the docker

```
sudo service docker start
```

And i can`t connect to aws use ssh

I am stuck,appreciate for any answer

linux version

```
Linux version 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Sep 26 15:12:11 UTC 2018
```

Comment: sudo systemctl start docker,does it work?

Comment: Thank you ,the connection will closed after that, i can`t connect to the aws by ssh util i restart the aws server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using t2.micro/nano EC2 in AWS? If yes, then please use t2.small or bigger EC2 instances

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).